# ERROR Al tratar de recibir mi array de php en js

Tags: javascript, php

Estoy tratando de recibir un **array** que envie de mi php en mi js, pero me pone

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' ".

Codigo PHP donde creo mi array:

```
$consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT id from giftcards where giftcard = '$codigo' and estado = 'No canjeado'");
$array = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta);
if($array){
    $respuesta = mysqli_query($conexion, "UPDATE giftcards set estado = 'Canjeado2' where id= $array[0] ");
    
    $array2 = array(
        "estado"=>"realizado"
    );

    $guardararray = json_encode($array2); 
    echo "$guardararray";
}
```

Codigo JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        const form = document.getElementById("form");
        form.addEventListener("submit", function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
        })

function validardatos(){
    var values = 
    {
        codigo: $('#Codigo').val(),
    };
    $.ajax(
    {
      data:  values,
      dataType: 'json',
      url:   'validacion.php',
      type:  'post',
    } 
    ) 
    
    var data= <?php echo json_encode($guardararray); ?>;

    if (data.length === 0) { 
      console.log("Está vacío!")
    }else{
      console.log("Hay Datos!")
    };
}
</script>
```

Comment: Primero de todo ve descartando cosas. Mira primero llamar al php directamente y comprueba si te devuelve un resultado correcto

Comment: Como podria hacer eso? O a que te refieres con si me devuelve un resultado correcto? La respuesta y consulta se ejecutan bien

Comment: Revisa como se hacen las peticiones ajax, pues no estás recogiendo el **response** de la petición, sino que estás presuponiendo que te va a devolver una variable `$guardararray` y que ademas la puedes tratar como si el javascript entendiera PHP usando sus delimitadores `<?php ?>` lo cual no es cierto y por eso te sale el error, que claramente dice (en inglés) que no esperaba encontrar el caracter `<` (y que deduzco que lo encuentra aqui: `var data= <?php...`). Busca ejemplos de `$.ajax` por la red e intentalo de nuevo sin meter php por medio de esa forma que te has inventado.

Comment: Perdon, sinceramente no soy muy bueno con ajax, es mucho pedirte un ejemplo? estoy viedo ejemplos pero en ninguno me queda claro como usar el response

Comment: Buscando "[ejemplo ajax jquery php](https://www.google.com/search?q=ejemplo+ajax+jquery+php)" en primer enlace me muestra [esta página](https://code.tutsplus.com/es/tutorials/how-to-use-ajax-in-php-and-jquery--cms-32494) donde debes bajar hasta el título que pone **Un ejemplo práctico de AJAX con PHP** y alli encontrarás todo lo que necesitas

Comment: Graciassss me solucionaste la vida jajajaj, estaba trancado ahi y no podia avanzar, muchas gracias<33, nose como fijar tu respuesta

Comment: No era una respuesta, no te preocupes, pero gracias. La respuesta la puedes poner tu ahora que ya lo has solucionado y supongo que ya tienes el código que te funciona bien, y en 48 horas la puedes aceptar para que la comunidad lo sepa y la pregunta no quede pendiente para siempre :-)

Comment: Tenkiu entonces jasgjg, donde me respondo?

Comment: Las respuestas estan un poco más abajo de los comentarios, donde pone "Tu respuesta" :-)

Answer (score 1):

La solucion fue simple, tenia que hacer bien mi array en php, quedo asi estructurada:

```
    echo json_encode(array('success' => 1));
}else{
    echo json_encode(array('success' => 0));
}
```

Y luego tenia que hacer un response en mi ajax y consultar los valores que habian dentro de ese array:

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'validacion.php',
            data: values,
            success: function(response)
            {
                var validacion = JSON.parse(response);
 
                if (validacion.success == "1"){
                    alert('Existe');
                }
                else{
                    alert('No Existe');
                }
           }
       });
     };
```

Comment: Buena respuesta :-)  Saludos!